# How to make (if not exist) and store local configuration value that is not shared?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing a rails app which saves items imported from the external API into the DB.
I'm looking for a way permanently to store the number of the imported items and the value can be updated. And the value is single, so I thought it would be right not to use the DB.
The Stored value should only be used locally and should not be shared with other servers using the app. So, the other server will store its own new value at the first.

I did googling and I found some ways for my goal, such as 'ENV' and PStore.
But ENV is not available to update the value and stores temporary value.
PStore should be used in the transaction block. I don't need such that excessive structure.
I just want to store the value permanently and locally, and use anywhere in the ruby code.

Can anyone give me a hint?
Thanks!

Comment: You want to _permanently store_ a number and want to be able to _update the value_. That is exactly what databases were invented for. Just use the database. Btw. why is it only one value. I guess you import data not only once. Could be a table _imports_ that has columns for the number of items imported by also who did the import, when did the import happen, etc...

Comment: @spickermann, Thanks for your comment. My app brings data by using external API and stores it into the DB. But quantity of the data is quite massive and I want the app to get only new data. To do that, I need to keep last index of data that has been already stored previously and can get only new data by passing it to the API.

Comment: Database, memcached, redis etc. It depends entirely on what you're looking to store and how fault tolerant that store needs to be. Beyond that the question is pretty much nonsensical. You can change `ENV` but it is process local. PStore is pretty much completely irrevant IMHO since any file based storage doesn't work in cloud based environments with an ephemeral file system like heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use redis. Store key/value on each server. Try this: https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/04/ruby-redis/